# MSV1_0 Subauthentication Package Registration

Tags: security, windows-server-2003, windows-authentication

I'm trying to register a simple MSV1_0 subauthentication package for MS Windows Server 2003. I created a dll which implements required functions described in MSDN. I copied my dll to system32 folder. After that, I created a registry key Auth255 (I also tried Auth128) with a REG_SZ value ,which specifies my dll name, to this location; HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0. I expect that it will create a test.txt file for debugging puposes when the dll is called, but it doesn't create the file. How can I make this work?

MSDN Link for this topic;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374786%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. I renamed registry key from Auth255 to Auth0 and my dll's init function called by MSV1_0. I realized that I forgot to export required functions from DLL. After these steps my dll worked fine.